# How to change color of element on hover and remove it when mouseout using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mouseover

I found the following Snippet (color changes randomly on hover)
But there is now mouseout state – i want the link color to change in its original state when not hovering the link.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "p" ).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css("color",getRandomColor());
    });

    function getRandomColor () {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/99upf1jz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouseleave event works exactly like the mouseover event. You can simply add it after the former, like this:

```
$( "p" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css("color",getRandomColor());
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/McNetic/99upf1jz/2/

If you really want to restore the "original" color (regardless what it was), you have to save it first. That could be done with a data element to each attribute (a global variable like suggested by other answers will not restore each element to it's respective color):

```
$( "p" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).data("original-color", $(this).css("color")).css("color",getRandomColor());
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("color", $(this).data("original-color"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/McNetic/99upf1jz/5/

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i've been looking for. The "original" color in my case is necessary because my links are black but also white on black background. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`mouseout`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)...

```
$( "p" ).mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).css("color","#000");
});
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/99upf1jz/1/

Comment: `mouseleave` is more reliable in this circumstnace. See the difference at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseleave` to apply a color when the mouse pointer moves from the link. 
Just change the `#000` to whichever color you choose.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "p" ).mouseover(function() {
$(this).css("color",getRandomColor());
});
$("p").mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).css("color","#000");
});

function getRandomColor () {
 var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
 var color = '#';
 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
 }
 return color;
    }
})
```

`mouseleave` appears to be a more reliable solution for what you ask in comparison to `mouseout`.

See this site for a comparison: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout

Answer (score 0):

You can store color of element in variable before changing it and set stored color to element when mouse is un-hoverd.

```
var color;
$( "p" ).mouseover(function() {
    color = $(this).css("color");
    $(this).css("color", getRandomColor());
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css("color", color);
});
```

```js
var color;
$( "p" ).hover(function() {
    color = $(this).css("color");
    $(this).css("color", getRandomColor());
}, function(){
    $(this).css("color", color);
});

function getRandomColor () {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test</p>
<p>test1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this after your $("p".mouseover()...

```
$( "p" ).mouseout(function() {
$(this).css("color","#222222");
});
```

instead of #222222, put whatever colour you wish to be the original colour.